# Marshal and umarshal BSON

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

**TL;DR: Does the MongoDB driver provide a function to marshal and unmarshal a single field of a document?**

This is a pretty straightforward question, but here's some context:

I have a worker responsible for synchronizing data between 2 separated databases. When it receives an event message, signalizing some document must sync, it selects the document in the primary database, and replicates it in another (it's a whole different database, not a replica set).

The thing is: I don't know the full structure of that document, so to preserve the data, I must unmarshal this document in a map `map[string]interface{}`, or a `bson.M` that works in the same fashion. But this seems like a lot of overhead, to unmarshal all this data I'm not even using, only to marshal it back to the other database.

So I thought about creating a structure that would just store the binary value of that document, without performing any marshal or unmarshal in order to reduce the overhead, like this:

```
type Document = map[string]Field

type Field struct {
    Type  bsontype.Type
    Value []byte
}

func (f Field) MarshalBSONValue() (bsontype.Type, []byte, error) {
    return f.Type, f.Value, nil
}

func (f *Field) UnmarshalBSONValue(btype bsontype.Type, value []byte) error {
    f.Type = btype
    f.Value = value
    return nil
}
```

With this structure I can indeed reduce how much of the data will be parsed, but now, I need to manually unmarshal the one value in this document I'll need to use.

So I'm wondering if the MongoDB driver would have some function such as:

```
// Hypothetical function to get the value of a BSON
var status string
if err := decodeBSON(doc['status'].Type, doc['status'].Value, &status); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

And

```
// Hypothetical function to set the value of a BSON
createdAt, err := encodeBSON(bsontype.Date, time.Now())
if err != nil {
    return err
}

doc["createdAt"] = Field{Type: bsontype.Date, Value: createdAt}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at bson.Raw, in particular, Raw.Lookup and Raw.Elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `Field` type in your code is equivalent to the driver's `bson.RawValue` type. By switching to `RawValue`, you can decode individual fields using the `RawValue.Unmarshal` method and encode fields using `bson.MarshalValue`, which returns the two components (type and data) that you need to construct a new `RawValue`.

An example of how you can use these methods to change a field based on its original value: The `Field` type in your code is equivalent to the driver's `bson.RawValue` type. By switching to `RawValue`, you can decode individual fields using the `RawValue.Unmarshal` method and encode fields using `bson.MarshalValue`, which returns the two components (type and data) that you need to construct a new `RawValue`.

An example of how you can change a field depending on its original value without unmarshalling all of the original document's fields: https://gist.github.com/divjotarora/06c5188138456070cee26024f223b3ee